# Saving a file with react Native

Tags: react-native

I'm working on an option in my React Native app to take data from a Realm database, convert it into csv, and send it via email.
I'm planning to use react-native-mail to send the email with the attachment.

How can I save a text file on the user's device, so I can supply it to the native email app with react-native-mail (or for any other purpose)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it out, but have you had a look at: https://github.com/Murriouz/react-native-file-manager? If that doesn't suit your needs, and you cannot find another option out there, your best bet would be to write your own native module. The docs have some details on doing this: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content

Comment: Looks like this module is related to this one: https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs (which has more and more recent commits)

Comment: Ah good find. I usually use http://react.parts to search for react native plugins. It has a decent list anyways.

Comment: @amirfl It seems that react-native-fs has been discontinued. Please use [https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) instead.